# Retrieve custom translations for a custom label via the metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, customlabel, translation

How can one retrieve these translations for a custom label via the metadata API?

[image]

Comment: You can retrieve Custom Label Translations by using "Translations" Tag in the Package.xml (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000319690&type=1&mode=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I retrieved the details using the [apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi). Example code below:

```
List<String> labels = new List<String>{'Demo1'};

MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

Map<String, String> valuesByKey = new Map<String, String>();
MetadataService.Translations translations = (MetadataService.Translations) service.readMetadata('Translations',
                new String[] { 'en_US' }).getRecords()[0];
for(MetadataService.CustomLabelTranslation customLabelTranslation : translations.customLabels) {
    if (labels.contains(customLabelTranslation.name)) {
        valuesByKey.put(customLabelTranslation.name, customLabelTranslation.label);
    }
}
System.debug(valuesByKey);
```

Answer (score 13):

You need to use both `CustomLabel` and `Translations`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
     <types>
      <members>*</members>
      <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types>
     <types>
      <members>*</members>
      <name>Translations</name>
    </types>
    <version>49.0</version>
</Package>
```

After retrieving with this, you are going to get all translated custom labels under `translations` folder. `labels` folder will have original versions. You can use a [language code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_translations.htm) in translations to pull specific language.

```
<types>
  <members>es</members>
  <name>Translations</name>
</types>
```

---

Also quoting **Usage** part in the above link

> When you use the retrieve() call to get translations in your
> organization, the files returned in the .translations folder only
> include translations for the other metadata types referenced in
> package.xml.

Comment: @snl oh sh... Seems like I am blind. Sorry about this. Please feel free to let the answerer know via comments etc. if they are answering the wrong question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your tips! i couldn't find this advice anywhere and keep getting translations files empty before knowing i had to retrieve also customlabels in the same package.xml. Thanks a lot @lafexlos

Answer (score 0):

I used CustomLabel instead of CustomLabels (plural) and worked for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
     <types>
      <members>*</members>
      <name>CustomLabel</name>
    </types>
     <types>
      <members>*</members>
      <name>Translations</name>
    </types>
    <version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```