# Metadata API not retrieving all language translation for custom labels

Tags: metadata-api, customlabel, translation, package.xml

I have created a Custom label with its translation on the setup:
[image: on]

I have also activated German language on the Setup->Translation Language Settings
[image]

However, when I retrieve it via Metadata API, why is the German translation not available?
[image]

I have followed instructions from [Retrieve custom translations for a custom label via the metadata API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310123/retrieve-custom-translations-for-a-custom-label-via-the-metadata-api) and edited my package.xml (manifest/package.xml) with:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Translations</name>
</types>
<types>
  <members>*</members>
  <name>CustomLabels</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
</types>
```

But I still cannot retrieve the German translation. Can someone please explain, what am I missing?

EDIT: The German translation file (de.translation-meta.xml) is somehow not retrieved.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Similar post:
[Retrieve custom translations for a custom label via the metadata API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310123/retrieve-custom-translations-for-a-custom-label-via-the-metadata-api)

When I use SFDX, I got it successfully by this command

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "CustomLabel, Translations"
```